# How to draw solid color in Texture Paint

Tags: texture-paint-mode

I use 4.0.2 Blender and I want to draw a sharp circle in Texture Paint mode just on character's eye. But result isn't solid but diffused (see the diffused circle I drew in the left window. But if I draw in the right window I got sharp circle as I wanted. As far as I see both draw tools have the same settings. But result is different. How can I achieve my goal to draw a sharp black circle in the left window?
[image]

Comment: Hello, could you please pack your images and share the object itself?

Answer (score 0):

I was helped by following steps:

1. Open editing mode
2. Select all points on my object
3. Press M and select "by distance"